# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
$('#maxpage').change(function(event){
    var pars = "max="+this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'Search', action: 'searchProfile')}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: pars,       
        asynchronous:false,                 
        success: function(data) {
            location.reload();//reload the page on the success
        },
    });
});
```

It throws an error on `location.reload();`
I want reload the whole page in the `success` function, but it gives me an error.

Comment: try calling it as window.location.reload()

Comment: do you use a `location` variable somewhere outside this code? Try `window.location.reload()` - if this works, you're shadowing it somewhere

Comment: Do you have an element named `location`? If you do, rename it.

Comment: `asynchronous:false` is wrong on at least two levels: there's no need to use a synchronous request (since you're passing a callback anyways), you never should, and the property name is not `asynchronous`.

Comment: `${createLink(controller: 'Search', action: 'searchProfile')}` -- I assume this gets replaced by an actual URL by the server script?

Comment: i am using groovy and grails